# How to check (in C/C++ code) if Openssl is installed on my computer?

Tags: c++, c, macros, openssl, portability

I would like to check if I have openssl installed using C/C++ code. Is it even possible? I mean, is there a macro, or something which will be a portable way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: On Windows: LoadLibrary !?

Comment: I asked about a portable solution, for at least windows/linux

Comment: Then the answer should be, there is none.

Comment: You should specify why you want to check. For example, if you need to know for installation reasons. If your application requires it, then you treat it as any other library on the platform. If using automatic dynamic linking, the OS will take care of the check and show the error to the user if missing. If using manual dynamic linking, the call will give you an error if missing.

Comment: Did you try with return value of system("openssl")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work on Windows and Linux:

```
#ifdef WIN32
libHandle = LoadLibrary( libraryName );
#else
libHandle = dlopen( libraryName, RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_NOW );
#endif
```